# How to use react native navigation to create a nested navigation? (Example: Stack navigator inside a Tab navigator)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a nested navigation as shown in the image below. I need to have a main TabNavigator and then inside one tab page, I need to add a StackNavigator to enable navigation to that tab page's sub pages. How can I do this?

Here's an illustration of what I need to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my repository ,I have created a sample app of your scenario.

Type 1
https://github.com/paraswatts/StackNavigator-inside-TabNavigator

Type 2
https://github.com/paraswatts/ParasWatts

Comment: Is it possible to do the reverse? A tab navigator inside a stack navigator?